# iOS - Keyboard type for decimal pad in Text Field from Settings bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

From Root.plist, I can only see five options to set the "Keyboard Type" value from a Text Field (PSTextFieldSpecifier) item:

> - Alphabet
> - Numbers and Punctuation
> - Number Pad
> - URL
> - Email Address

Is there a way to set the value to decimal pad, just like you can do it from Interface Builder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it's not possible to assign the Keyboard Type equals to `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` for a *PSTextFieldSpecifier*